# No puedo coencatarme con la bd

Tags: mysql, mysqlconnector

buen dia
tengo un problema
resulta que mi pagina la puse con un VPN para poder mostrarla entonces estoy conectado a varias subredes
de los pisos del edificio pues resulta que en el piso en el que estoy si funciona bien la bases de datos pero en los demas pisos no incluso en uno ni se ve la pagina
pero en los que si se ven fuera de mi piso me dice que no conecte a mi base de datos

[image]

Comment: Habilitaste el acceso remoto en Mysql?. Habilitaste la ip de la VPN en Mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Por tu descripción del problema parece que tienes problemas con las redes. Según entiendo, en tu red local funciona. Sin embargo al salir de esta ya no.

Mira si en la configuración tienes algún tipo de protección ante accesos de fuera de la red local o de un distinto rango de IPs.